# How to start activity for result in jetpack compose on a button click

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The implementation is in `Java`, want to this implementation in `Jetpack` compose on an icon click. Button click to show speech to text dialog:

```java
mVoiceBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            speak();
        }
    });
```

The main problem is to create this specific `Intent` in compose:

```java
private void speak() {
        //intent to show speech to text dialog
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL
                , RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Hi Speak Somethimh");

        //start intent
        try {
            //in there was no error
            //show dialog
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            //IF THERE WERE SOME ERROR
            //GET MESSAGE OF ERROR AND SHOW
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    //receive voice input and handle it
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    //GET TEXT ARRAY FROM VOICE INTENT
                    ArrayList<java.lang.String> result;
                    result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    // SRT TO TEXT VIEW
                    mTextTv.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                break;
            }
            default:
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing this in Compose yet? If so, what did your attempt look like? :-) @Sharan

Comment: `rememberLauncherForActivityResult` I got one implementation on how to launch with `LaunchedEffect` but that was completely different purpose, unable to couple that solution to the required one

Comment: Alright. Do you have any actual Compose code you could share with us so that we help you piece it together? :-)

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#activity_result)?

Answer (score 4):

Remember launcher activity for result and launching pending intent is a solution I could find, there could be a better way.

```kotlin
        val intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
        intent.putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM
        )
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault())
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Hi Speak Somethimh")
        val context = LocalContext.current

        val pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)
        var code by remember {
            mutableStateOf("")
        }
        val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
            contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()
        ) {
            if (it.resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                return@rememberLauncherForActivityResult
            }

            //GET TEXT ARRAY FROM VOICE INTENT
            val result = it.data?.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS)

            if (result !== null) {
                code = result[0] ?: ""

            }
        }
```

```kotlin
Button(onClick = {
                launcher.launch(
                    IntentSenderRequest.Builder(pendIntent)
                        .build()
                )
            }) {
                
 }
```

Comment: Why would you use `ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()` when the [`ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult) contract already exists for taking an `Intent` directly?

Comment: Got it Thanks, I was looking for this contract only

Comment: @Sharan This my implementation which I recommend: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70711094/6805392